# Haud sciō an ego ita dīxerim

Tags: grammar-choice, meaning, lingua-latina-per-se-illustrata

In the line 84 page 264 of *Lingua Latine per se illustrata*, Gubernātor says

> Haud sciō an ego ita dīxerim, sed pro­
> fectō lībertās mihi vītā cārior est. ...

The part I am interested is

> Haud sciō an ego ita dīxerim

In the margin the book says that *haud sciō an dīxerim* means *fortasse dīxī*, but not is clear to me how this is  affected with *ego*, *ita*, concretely the *ita*, which I still have little to no idea of how to use it, even I am in page 264 of *Lingua Latina per se illustrata*.

Edit: I would be useful get explained it in spanish

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the questions you are asking, it seems that you are reading only *Lingua Latina per se illustrata*.
It's a good series for all I know, but does not work well alone.
In order to get a deeper understanding of how some things work, you need a source that explains things in a language you already understand.
It could be a grammar or another textbook.
Immersion alone is not an efficient route to understanding.

The inclusion of *ego* (and *ita*) in both *ego ita dixerim* and *fortasse ego ita dixi* is optional.
Both can be understood from context, and the subject pronoun need not be used in Latin the way it must in Spanish and many other Romance languages.
The person is already communicated with the ending.

The word *ita*, "so", is more important and I would not drop it out here.
It is a bit odd that the suggested alternative does not contain it.
It depends on how you phrase what follows.
Compare the English "Maybe I haven't said so, but" and "Maybe I haven't said that", which hardly differ much in meaning.

The alternative offered has a parallel in English:

> I don't know if I said so, but…
> Maybe I [already] said so, but…

One uses an indirect question (a concept explained in textbooks and grammars) and the other uses "maybe" to convey uncertainty.
The overall meaning is essentially the same.

Comment: The suggested alternative is for *haud sciō an dīxerim*, not for *Haud sciō an ego ita dīxerim*

Comment: @Dolphínus I know, and my point is that it could have been either way, depending on how the rest of it was to be structured. That alternative is not to be taken as an absolute truth but as a hint. I added a sentence to clarify what I mean by the optionality of "so" or *ita*.

Comment: And do you know some grammar textbook?

Comment: Preferibly in Spanish

Comment: @Dolphínus In English there's for example [Allen and Greenough (free online edition)](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/alphabet). I don't know of anything in Spanish, but just about any Latin grammar will get you started.

Comment: The subject is not needed in Spanish either; it is less emphatic than in Latin (in the process of moving towards the French system), but it is still optional unless for emphasis. (@Dolphínus The most verbatim Spanish translaton I can think of would be, “Apenas sé si yo así dijera…”, which doesn’t flow very well, but should be at least intelligible.)

Comment: Also, if you’re comfortable reading Italian, the _Lingva Latina per se illvstrata_ series has a short grammar volume as well. In the original version, this was in Latin only, like the rest of the series, but the current primary publisher, Vivarium Novum, have changed it to an Italian version titled _Grammatica di Consultazione_. It’s available [through their website here](https://vivariumnovum.it/scolastica/latino/corso-base/grammatica-di-consultazione).

Comment: @Dolphínus:    In Spanish, I've just discovered [*Latine disco*](https://www.amazon.es/Latine-disco-lingua-latina-illustrata/dp/8493579815#aw-udpv3-customer-reviews_feature_div).